# Set the property of a form element from directive

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, forms, email

I'm making an angular sign up form and have made a directive to check valid e-mails. The directive uses [Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)'s   `isEmail(str [, options])` to do the work of checking regex for me.

The directive is called `validator`:

```
<form name="signUpForm">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : signUpForm.email.$invalid && !signUpForm.email.$pristine }">
        <input type="email" name="email" validator="isEmail" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
        <p ng-show="signUpForm.email.$invalid && !signUpForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">E-mail is required.</p>
        <p ng-show="signUpForm.email.$invalid">E-mail is invalid.</p>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="signUp()" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="signUpForm.$invalid">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Angular: I want to somehow return `false`, or set `$invalid` to be true if an invalid e-mail, and display "E-mail is invalid" message (`<p ng-show="signUpForm.email.$invalid">E-mail is invalid.</p>`). I'm not sure how to set that `$invalid` property from the directive though:

```
angular
    .module('v2v')
    .directive('validator', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                elem.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
                    elem.$invalid = validator.isEmail(this.value);
                });
            }
        };
}]);
```

Comment: I'm not using a version of Angular that includes $validators yet, but I use setValidity('isEmail', true);

Answer (score 1):

Angular inputs have built in [email](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D) validation, but if you need to add your own custom validation, you can easily do this by adding your own validation function to the model controllers [`$validators`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators):

```
angular
    .module('v2v')
    .directive('validator', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, modelController) {
              modelController.$validators.email = function () {
                return validator.isEmail(this.value);
              }
            }
        };
}]);
```

There's also no need to roll your own notification elements, you can angular's [ng-messages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) drective to do it for you:

```
<div ng-messages="signUpForm.email.$error">
  <div ng-message="required">Email is required</div>
  <div ng-message="email">E-mail is invalid.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nick, thanks for this. I wanted to use Angular out-of-the-box input e-mail validation, but the `[pattern="string"]` argument seems to look for me to provide  a regex. So I'd rather another library do the proper regex for me.

Comment: @Growler you shouldn't need to provide a pattern, unless you do _not_ want the default regex (which is the regex that chromium uses, so relatively trustworth)